# Concatenate value by delimiter based on key match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
KEY     DATE        STATUS      Item   ORDEREDQTY SHIPPEDQTY        Concat (ouput)
1       05/11/2015  Dispatch    123     3           1            1 | 05/11/2015 | Dispatch | 123 | 3 | 1 | 321 | 2 | 1  
1       05/11/2015  Dispatch    321     2           1
2       14/11/2015  Dispatch    456     3           2            2 | 14/11/2015 | Dispatch | 456 | 3 | 2 | 678 | 2 | 1  
2       14/11/2015  Dispatch    678     2           1
```

How to do the above?

I need to concatenate `Item`, `originalqty` and `shipqty` if `Key` is matching. Above has key value as 1 and in the output column I should get the value which are having key as 1 and concatenating last three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table ([KEY] int,DATE date,STATUS varchar(50),Item int,ORDEREDQTY int,SHIPPEDQTY int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2015-11-05','Dispatch',123,3,1),
(1,'2015-11-05','Dispatch',321,2,1),
(2,'2015-11-14','Dispatch',456,3,2),
(2,'2015-11-14','Dispatch',678,2,1)

Select A.*
      ,ConcatString=Case when RowNr=1 then cast([Key] as varchar(25)) + ' | ' + cast(Date as varchar(25)) +  ' | ' +  Status  +  ' | ' + B.String  else '' end
 From  (Select *,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By [KEY] Order by (Select NULL)) From @YourTable) A
 Cross Apply (
               Select String=Stuff((Select  ' | ' + cast(Item as varchar(25)) + 
                                      ' | ' + cast(ORDEREDQTY as varchar(25)) + 
                                      ' | ' + cast(SHIPPEDQTY as varchar(25)) 
                                      From  @YourTable
                                      Where [Key]=A.[Key]
                                      For XML Path ('')),1,3,'') 

             ) B
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: cappeletti : - Thanks you very much for the solution, but in your solution Dispatch and date are repeating which i don't want. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @SomashekharKendule  Just a moment

Comment: @SomashekharKendule Quick fix.  Updated Answer

Comment: @SomashekharKendule  Good to know.  Cheers